# Cellular automation for dungeon generation

Tags: algorithm, math, game-development

I am trying to make a roguelike game and want to use a cellular automation on it. Are the any standard rules for dungeon generation?

The best what I have found is:

- set 1 if there is 4 or more neighbors cells with 1 on it.
- set 0 if it not.

Comment: Looks like this rule will result in every dungeon turning into the smallest convex shape that contains the initial shape.

Comment: Are you trying to make a maze? A system of caverns? The backrooms?